# Heroku rejecting an app with mailers and Sendgrid (remote: NameError: uninitialized constant Mail)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sendgrid

Heroku is failing to install my App after mailers/Sendgrid. The error I'm getting is:

remote:        Removing sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant Mail

### Its working on the local environment useing gmail.

The mailing functionality is to send an email to admin when a comment has been posted on their article and email to the "Followers" when an article has been posted.

## app/mailers/commentmailer.rb

```
class CommentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
```

def comment_created(comment, article)
    @comment = comment
    @article = article

```
mail( to: @article.user.email ,
      from:'no_reply@gmail.com' ,
      subject:'A comment on your post.')
```

end
end

## app/mailers/article_mailer

```
class ArticleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
```

def article_created(follower, article)
    @article = article
    follower.each do |f|
      mail to: f.email, from:'no_reply@gmail.com', subject: "An article has been created"
    end
  end
end

## views/followers/new.html.erb

```
  <h3> Stay up tp date with my new articles </h3>
    <p> You will be sent an email whenever a new article was posted </p>
    <%= form_for @follower do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name, "Your Name:" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <br>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <br>
      <%= f.submit('Follow me')  %>
    <% end %>
```

## config/environments/production.rb

```
      Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {  host: "https://personal-blog22.herokuapp.com " }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => '587',
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

## config/environments/development.rb

```
    # For better error to work on Vagrant VM
BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! "0.0.0.0/0"

Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.consider_all_requests_local
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
end
```

## config/application

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module PersonalBlog
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true


    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:               "smtp.gmail.com",
      port:                   587,
      domain:                "ruby.blog100.com",
      user_name:             "XXXXXXgmail.com",
      password:              "XXXXX",
      authentication:        :plain,
      enable_starttls_auto:  true
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make changes in `config/environments/production.rb`

change :

```
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

to

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => '587',
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Because `Mail` is not initialize in your heroku environment. In your local environment it might initialize in local gem or package.

Code you updated in question seems don't have end in file.Try copy and paste below code in your production.rb file. It will work for you.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {  host: "https://personal-blog22.herokuapp.com " }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

Comment: remote:        SyntaxError: /tmp/build_1f1b0ddb960a56cf651d218b8a112bd8/config/environments/production.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: Now its compiling about an "end". Cant see anything wrong with end.

Comment: Can you update your production.rb . I think you didn't remove end from file.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please copy production.rb code from there. It will work for you.

Comment: Somewhere in your production.rb file there is another `end` present. that is causing this issue.

Comment: I did copy the your copy exactly as its but still having the same error. There probably is! but I could not post it this extra end anywhere.

Comment: https://github.com/FaisalFehad/Personal_blog/tree/mailer this is the my code branch. You might be able to spot it.